# .Net Core 3.1 adding additional config.json file to configuration argument in Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parameters, blazor

I need to add another configuration file to my .Net Core Blazor project.
Other sources (such as [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configuration-in-asp-net-core/)) mention using configuration builder in .Net core 2.2, but since in 3.1 the configuration is passed as a parameter into Startup, I have no way of appending another config onto it as far as I can tell. Maybe I'm looking at it wrong, but I'm assuming that the configuration passed in as a param has important configuration properties, therefor building it my self with just the additional config file seems like it leave those config properties out.

Ex: Doesn't work but should paint a picture of what I'm trying to do.

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
      Configuration = configuration;
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(configuration)
              .AddJsonFile("accountconstants.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it in `Program.cs` i.e. earlier in the pipeline rather than in `Startup.cs`.

Example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;

                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: Definitely missed that, and it appears to work; this should be mentioned in the MS docs. Thank you!

Comment: It is, link is in my answer below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configureappconfiguration

Answer (score 8):

Your approach should work, but needs a little bit of tweaking.

The configuration that you create needs to be added to the DI Container.
The documentation for this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configureappconfiguration).

I've achieved it as well in Azure Functions and other projects through the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(provider => new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile("accountconstants.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build());
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so I can even add the configuration to a service, that'll come in handy for less abstraction in the future if I'm adding only a single config file to a service instance. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like AddJsonFile() doesn't exists anymore in .NET Core 5.

Comment: @IngoB It still exists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#json-configuration-provider

Comment: Ah, I had to add the "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" package!